# Save session of Play Audio file

Tags: iphone

i want save play Audio file session when my application Terminate.
is this possible in iPhone?

i am developing **ebook** application in this application i have add new functionality (i.e when application launch,**page scroll and Audio file play simultaneously** ) and while application terminate and re- launch the application, application start last state of application.

my query is how to **save session state of Audio file**, i have done save state of scroll offset but i don't not know how can i do save state of session of Audio file.

does anyone know above of the query ?

Thank you,
Milan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `AVAudioPlayer`, the `currentTime` property allows getting and setting the current position in your audio file.

[AVAudioPlayer Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime)